Vega visualization showing error for path mark in Kibana (Kibana v8.15.2)
I am using Kibana v8.15.2, and I’m trying to create a Vega visualization. Visualization rendering correct. However, I am facing the following error:

My Vega spec is:

{
  "$schema": "https://vega.github.io/schema/vega/v5.json",
  "data": [
    {
      "name": "routes",
      "url": {
        "%context%": true,
        "%timefield%": "@timestamp",
        "index": "my-index",
        "body": {
          "size": 20,
          "_source": ["source.geo.location", "destination.geo.location"]
        }
      },
      "format": {"property": "hits.hits"},
      "transform": [
        {
          "type": "geopoint",
          "projection": "projection",
          "fields": ["_source.source.geo.location.lon", "_source.source.geo.location.lat"],
          "as": ["sourceX", "sourceY"]
        },
        {
          "type": "geopoint",
          "projection": "projection",
          "fields": ["_source.destination.geo.location.lon", "_source.destination.geo.location.lat"],
          "as": ["targetX", "targetY"]
        },
        {
          "type": "linkpath",
          "shape": "curve",
          "sourceX": {"field": "sourceX"},
          "sourceY": {"field": "sourceY"},
          "targetX": {"field": "targetX"},
          "targetY": {"field": "targetY"}
        }
      ]
    }
  ],
  "marks": [
    {
      "type": "path",
      "from": {"data": "routes"},
      "encode": {
        "enter": {
          "strokeWidth": {"value": 2}
        },
        "update": {
          "path": {"field": "path"},
          "stroke": {"value": "blue"}
        }
      }
    },
  ]
}


Error Message:
Invalid SVG path, incorrect parameter type

Expected: Error free visualization
